# Is there a fast convolution that works with large numbers?

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

I am doing convolutions of a lot of reasonably long arrays. The values in them are also big although they fit within the scope of float64.  Unfortunately, scipy's [convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)  gives the wrong answer when it uses the fft method. Here is a MWE:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve
import numpy as np

A = np.array([0] + [1e100]*10000)
convolve(A, A)
```

This gives the wrong output of:

```
array([ 9.15304445e+187, -7.04080342e+187,  1.00000000e+200, ...,
        3.00000000e+200,  2.00000000e+200,  1.00000000e+200])
```

It is fast though:

```
%timeit convolve(A, A)
458 µs ± 5.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

You can get the right answer with:

```
convolve(A, A, method="direct")
array([0.e+000, 0.e+000, 1.e+200, ..., 3.e+200, 2.e+200, 1.e+200])
```

However this is much slower:

```
%timeit convolve(A, A, method="direct")
23.4 ms ± 511 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Is there any way to get the right answer quickly? I am happy to use any library that is freely available.

---

I get the same problem with less extreme inputs sizes:

```
A = np.array([0] + [1e10]*10000)
convolve(A, A)
array([1.96826156e+08, 1.35742176e+08, 1.00000000e+20, ...,
       3.00000000e+20, 2.00000000e+20, 1.00000000e+20])
```

## Bounty

The bounty is for the less extreme example of

```
 A = np.array([0] + [1e10]*10000)
```

My input arrays will always be made of integers

Comment: Do you have a version of FFTW that's compiled for `long double`, assuming your machine supports the wider type properly?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't but do you think it would help?

Comment: The error just appears huge due to the scale of the result. `A = [0] + [10] * 10000` exhibits the same behavior: The first two results are about 12 powers of 10 smaller than the later results. It's just that because you run at a scale of 1e200, it's 1e188 instead of 1e-12. It's just numerical noise scaled up. For any "normal" scale it would appear "close to zero"

Comment: Put another way: Compared to 1e200, 1e187 is close to zero within the limits of floating point math.

Comment: @Homer512. Exactly. And more available precision would potentially help with that by reducing the quantization noise

Comment: @MadPhysicist true but I don't think it will help. Even if long double gave us 20 more decimal digits (which would be much), the result would still be about 1e167. I'd argue that the relative error is more important than the absolute error and therefore the results with normal double precision are either fine as they are or would never be fine with floating point math since no hardware will ever have 200 decimal digits mantissa.

Comment: Are you looking for exact results? You seem to want exact results, especially since you say your inputs will always be integers, but if you want exact results, that failed before you even began working - even the simple literal `1e100` already incurs rounding error. For example, `1e100` isn't even a multiple of 10 - `1e100 % 10` gives `4.0`. You are far past the point where floating point stops being able to represent all integers.

Comment: If you want fast, exact convolution of large sequences of arbitrary-precision integers, you'd need an approach based on a [number-theoretic transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_over_a_ring#Number-theoretic_transform). NumPy and SciPy won't help you there, though [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/discrete.html#number-theoretic-transform) has a number-theoretic transform.

Comment: At the scales you're working at, `1e100 + 2e100 - 3e100` gives `3.885337784451458e+84` instead of 0, for the same reason `0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` gives `5.551115123125783e-17`. It's hard to imagine an application where these convolution results are a problem, but `1e100 + 2e100 - 3e100 != 0` is fine.

Comment: (I don't know if a number-theoretic transform actually pays off for this combination of value scale and sequence length. My tests time out with or without the number-theoretic transform, since doing the convolution in bignum arithmetic is just inherently so much slower than doing it in floating point, where the precision is so much lower and the hardware gives so much support. If you really do need exact large integer arithmetic, there's no getting around the performance hit, though.)

Answer (score 4):

With no other comments coming in, I might as well turn my comments into an answer, albeit not a very satisfying one:

### Explaining the FFT method result

This situation is simply a case of the limited accuracy of floating point computations, combined with their high range of values resulting in large absolute errors when faced with large absolute values. For the finer details and explanation of this, we can of course turn to Goldberg's ["What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163).

Simplifying a bit: double precision with its 53 bits mantissa gives us about 16 decimal digits (`log10(2**53)`). This means that even under the best circumstances, a computations on values around 1e0 will have numeric errors of around 1e-16, which then of course may accumulate. We can see this by scaling down the convolution

```py
A = np.array([0] + [1e0]*10000)
convolve(A, A)
array([-1.10378972e-12, -2.39154439e-12,  1.00000000e+00, ...,
        3.00000000e+00,  2.00000000e+00,  1.00000000e+00])
```

An error in the ballpark of 1e-12 is about what we can expect and nobody with a base-understanding of floating point arithmetic would bat an eye at a computation with that sort of numeric error.

Now we scale the result up to 1e200. What happens? We still have the same limited mantissa. Therefore the error scales with it. And that is exactly what we see.

```py
A = np.array([0] + [1e100]*10000)
convolve(A, A)
array([1.97142496e+188, 3.52040171e+187, 1.00000000e+200, ...,
      3.00000000e+200, 2.00000000e+200, 1.00000000e+200])
```

Notice how there is still a factor of about 1e12 between the result and the error. The relative error (or signal-to-noise ratio, if you prefer) is the same.

### Explaining the direct method result

Why is the direct convolution not affected? Simply because this is a somewhat artificial dataset. The moment you start doing any serious work with these datasets or use more variable data, the seeming advantage of direct convolution evaporates. We can demonstrate this by convolving random values in single precision and comparing the result to a convolution in double precision.

```py
A = np.random.random(10000).astype('f4')
fourier = convolve(A, A)
direct = convolve(A, A, method='direct')
A = A.astype('f8')
reference = convolve(A, A, method='direct')
abs(direct - reference).sum()
23.32324818390154
abs(fourier - reference).sum()
3.2571286909226727
```

The fft method in single precision is closer to the direct method in double precision than the direct method in single precision. This indicates that the fft method will generally be more accurate which makes sense since it involves fewer arithmetic operations and therefore fewer chances to add rounding errors.

### Mitigating the issue

Is there something we can do? Not really. Using long double was suggested. However, the 80 bit x86 format only gives us 64 bits mantissa, which is 20 decimal digits. So our error would still be somewhere around 1e184. The largest format in IEEE-754 is binary256 with 237 bits mantissa. That gives 72 digits, turning our error into 1e132. Still a huge absolute number.

One would need 664 bits mantissa to accurately represent values ranging from 1e200 to 1e0. At that point we are deep in the realm of arbitrary precision numbers and the question was whether we can find a fast and accurate solution. So, no.

What you should do instead is look at the relative values. 1e188 is huge but it is tiny compared to 1e200. Scale the results by the absolute maximum and don't look back.

### Side note

Speaking of scaling results, your computations are dangerously close to the range limit on the exponent. Since [convolution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html) and many other operations can simply be scaled by a constant, I suggest you bring your numbers down to a more reasonable value range. The issue is that you run the risk that intermediate results may overflow the exponent.

For accurate scaling that never changes bits in the mantissa (except for denormalized numbers) and that can be inverted accurately, I recommend using powers of two.

```py
def scale_down(arr):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    scale = abs(arr).max()
    _, power = math.frexp(scale)
    scale = math.ldexp(1., power)
    arr = arr * (1. / scale)
    return arr, scale

A, scale = scale_down(A)
convolve(A, A) * scale**2

# or for two:
A, ascale = scale_down(A)
B, bscale = scale_down(B)
convolve(A, B) * (ascale * bscale)
```

A practical example where this would be necessary with your current values is taking the vector norm of your convolution result.

```py
A = np.array([0] + [1e200]*10000)
np.linalg.norm(A)
inf
A, scale = scale_down(A)
np.linalg.norm(A) * scale
1e202
```

Comment: Maybe karatsuba is the answer?

Comment: @Simd You mean the multiplication algorithm? How?

Comment: Convolution and polynomial multiplication are basically the same thing.

Comment: @Simd Well, yeah. You can express the convolution in different forms but as long as you do it with floating point math you will get numeric noise. But maybe I don't understand the larger picture of what you want to do. Do you have some form of integer restriction? Because right now it looks like you are hung up on some noise that is only visible because your test data is entirely composed of a single huge value. Is this truly representative of what you want to do?

Comment: Note that the 'direct' method gives the right answer, as shown in the question. The problem is caused by numerical precision in the FFT. But Karatsuba does not use the FFT. Also in the bounty question there are no huge values.

Comment: @Simd a) You'll notice that the relative error in your 1e10 input is the same as in the 1e100 input, which is the same as in the 1e0 case I showed. b) Do you have any comments on my code that shows that the FFT method is more accurate when used with random data? That's why I asked whether your actual application uses such as specific dataset where all values are the same.

Comment: My data is not random sadly and shows the kind of errors you see in my example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254816/discussion-between-homer512-and-simd).

Answer (score 2):

You're working far beyond the scale where floating point can actually represent all integers. At those scales, even `1e100` itself is already an approximation, and you get results like

```
In [1]: 1e100 % 10
Out[1]: 4.0

In [2]: 1e100+2e100-3e100
Out[2]: 3.885337784451458e+84
```

And `scipy.signal.convolve` with `method='direct'` isn't immune to these issues. Here's an example that gives 7.77067557e+084 when you would have wanted 0:

```
In [20]: a1 = numpy.array([1e50, 2e50,-3e50])

In [21]: a2 = numpy.array([1e50, 1e50, 1e50])

In [22]: scipy.signal.convolve(a1, a2, method='direct')
Out[22]: 
array([ 1.00000000e+100,  3.00000000e+100,  7.77067557e+084,
       -1.00000000e+100, -3.00000000e+100])
```

So there are 3 possible cases here.

- Case 1: You're in some incredibly specific, extremely weird situation where nothing I just demonstrated is a problem, but the specific convolution results you've posted *are* a problem. In that case, you'll need to be much more specific about what sorts of inputs you need to handle and what requirements you have for the output.
- Case 2: The convolution results you posted are actually fine. In that case, you don't need to change anything.
- Case 3: The rounding errors I just demonstrated are a problem. In that case, you're going to need to change more than just your convolution algorithm.

---

In case 2, we're done. I hope we're not in case 1, because historically speaking, cases like that tend to end in an unproductive argument in the comments and a closed question.

Let's talk about case 3!

If your real values are as simple as your example values, just small integers times a scale factor, then maybe you can represent your arrays as an array of small integers and a separate scale factor. Then you can track the scale factor manually and do your convolution in native integer arithmetic, or even do the convolution with a floating-point FFT and just round all the results to the nearest integer if you're confident you won't lose too much precision. (You need to be able to use a single scale factor for a whole array, though - if you want to have `10**100` and `10**101` in the same array, you can factor out `10**100` and end up with values that fit into native ints, but if you've got `10**100` and `10**200` in the same array, that won't work.)

If your real values aren't so simple, then you're going to need to use arbitrary-precision arithmetic. **This will be painfully, unavoidably slow**, but if you need the precision, you can't get around the performance hit.

You might still be able to use an efficient algorithm, though. The fast Fourier transform behind efficient floating-point convolution generalizes to the integers mod a prime, as the [number-theoretic transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_over_a_ring#Number-theoretic_transform). You can use a number-theoretic transform in place of a floating-point FFT to perform integer convolution the same way a floating-point FFT convolution would work. The outputs will all be reduced mod whatever prime you pick, but as long as you pick a big enough prime (and remember to fix up negative numbers afterward), this isn't an issue.

I don't know where the actual performance breakpoints are for a number-theoretic transform vs direct computation of the convolution. I wrote up an implementation using SymPy's [`sympy.discrete.convolutions.convolution_ntt`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/discrete.html#sympy.discrete.convolutions.convolution_ntt), which I've provided below, but both the NTT convolution and the direct approach are so slow at these input scales that I wasn't able to time them on the sites I usually use. A faster NTT might help - SymPy isn't built for speed - but it's quite possible that for the value scales and input lengths you're working with, direct computation will just be better.

Anyway, here's the NTT-based code I wrote:

```
from sympy.discrete.convolutions import convolution_ntt
from sympy.ntheory.generate import isprime

def pick_prime(l1, l2):
    # All input and output values will get reduced mod p.
    # We want a p big enough that positive outputs are unchanged,
    # and negative numbers map to a value distinguishable from values that
    # were originally positive.
    # (If this p is somehow smaller than the biggest input value, that's
    # actually fine - the output will be okay.)
    # Additionally, due to constraints of the algorithm SymPy implements,
    # we need (p-1) % 2**k == 0, where 2**k is the first power of 2 that's
    # greater than or equal to the convolution output length.
    
    # Phase 1: figure out a bound on the range of values we need to distinguish.
    # We don't need a good bound, so here's a pretty weak one.
    # Positive outputs can't be greater than
    #   max(map(abs, l1)) * max(map(abs, l2)) * min(len(l1), len(l2))
    # and negative outputs can't be less than negative that.
    # Bound computation isn't the bottleneck, though, so a stronger bound
    # might be better.
    p = 1 + (max(map(abs, l1)) *
             max(map(abs, l2)) *
             min(len(l1), len(l2)) *
             2)
    # Phase 2: find the first p greater than that with p-1 % 2**k == 0.
    res_len = len(l1) + len(l2) - 1
    if res_len & (res_len - 1):
        # res_len is not a power of 2
        power_of_2 = 2 ** res_len.bit_length()
    else:
        power_of_2 = res_len
    residue = (p-1) % power_of_2
    if residue:
        p -= residue
        p += power_of_2
    while not isprime(p):
        p += power_of_2
    return p
    
def ntt_convolve(l1, l2):
    # Takes and returns lists, not arrays.

    # Could save some time across multiple convolutions by
    # computing usable primes in advance.
    p = pick_prime(l1, l2)
    # A stronger bound might need a different threshold computation.
    threshold = p // 2
    
    conv_result = convolution_ntt(l1, l2, p)
    return [x if x <= threshold else x - p for x in conv_result]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively efficient implementation using integer multiplication on Github:
[int_convolve.py](https://github.com/ohadkel/int_convolve/blob/main/int_convolve.py). Roughly speaking, we pack the arrays of integers in bigints, use fast multiplication, and restore the convolution of the arrays from the product.

Note that it contains two (similar) implementations; the  faster of which assumes the availability of the `gmpy2` package. Note it gives exact integer results, rather than float values.

On my 2022 laptop, it takes `2.1` seconds for `2^19 x 2^19` convolution with `100`-bit ints.